# Installing git from source is larger (16MiB) than from Debian package (2MiB)

Tags: git, debian, static-linking

Why is installing Git from source (16MiB) larger than installing from the Debian repos (2MiB)?

Context: I'm building Git from source on Debian stretch for a minimal continuous integration Docker image.  I need a newer version of Git than what's available in the Debian stretch repos.

If I install git with `apt`, the Git binary is 2MiB.

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install git

$ du -h /usr/bin/git
2.0M    /usr/bin/git
```

If I install Git from source, the binary is 16MiB.  I've tried to emulate the Debian build process.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc libc-dev zlib1g-dev curl ca-certificates make libssl-dev
export GIT_VERSION=2.23.0
curl -L https://github.com/git/git/archive/v${GIT_VERSION}.tar.gz --output git.tar.gz

tar xvf git.tar.gz
cd git-${GIT_VERSION}

# Options for building git
export NO_CURL=1 NO_EXPAT=1 NO_GETTEXT=1 NO_PERL=1 NO_PYTHON=1 NO_TCLTK=1
export NO_INSTALL_HARDLINKS=1 NO_OPENSSL=1 NO_CROSS_DIRECTORY_HARDLINKS=1

export CFLAGS='-g -O -fdebug-prefix-map=/=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
make -j8 prefix=/usr gitexecdir=/usr/lib/git-core install
make prefix=/usr gitexecdir=/usr/lib/git-core install

$ du -h /usr/bin/git
16M     /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: Try running `strip` on the generated binary to see if it's debug symbols that are increasing the size.

Comment: Thank you. `strip` reduced it to 2.8M. Make it an answer?  I'm somewhat curious where Debian strips the binaries.  I didn't see it in the Debian build rules.  I'm also curious how Debian squeezed the last 800KB.

Comment: debhelper, one of the Debian build tools, strips binaries automatically unless told not to, because Debian Policy requires it.  The rest of the increase in size is probably additional features that have been added over time, since most of those features are all built into one binary.